# js namespaces and variable scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have custom javascript namespace like with following structure

```
myns.controllers.home = {
    init = function(){
    },
    doSomething: function(){
        var cars = 100; // simple example
        var url = 'someurl';
        myns.ajaxHelper.execute(url, { id: id }, myns.controllers.home.jobUtils.callback);
    }
}
myns.controllers.home.jobUtils.callback = function (cars) {
    alert(cars.lenght); // cars is undefined?       
}
```

why cars variable is undefined here and how would you solve/refactor this?

Comment: yes, why is that matter to this question?

Comment: you are checking `lenght` property but `car` is `Number` and it doesnt have `length`, [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p5z2gjup/) looks good

Comment: my mistake for that length property, I forgot to clean it before, but basically   nothing changes, since cars is undefined.

Comment: 1. Your spelling of length is wrong. 
2. integers don't have a length property, in this case your `cars` var is int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try declaring variable as a ns property:

```
myns.controllers.home = {
  cars: 100,
  init: ...
```

Comment: Will go with global variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
myns.ajaxHelper.execute(url, { id: id }, myns.controllers.home.jobUtils.callback()); //for executing a function

var cars = 100; // simple example
myns.ajaxHelper.execute(url, { id: id }, myns.controllers.home.jobUtils.callback(cars)); //to pass a variable into a function
```

I think you miss '()'  open and close bracket when executing the function

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but I think this might help:

If you create a better callback function that captures the local `cars` value, you could:

```
myns.ajaxHelper.execute(url, 
                        { id: id }, 
                        function(data){
                         myns.controllers.home.jobUtils.callback(data, cars)
                        });
```

then define your callback as:

```
myns.controllers.home.jobUtils.callback = function (data, cars) {
    alert(cars.lenght); // cars is undefined?       
}
```

although quite how a value of `100` might have a `length` is unclear to me. Maybe I misunderstood.